# Is there a way to test the NFC application in Automation test module?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm new to NFC development. I am in need of testing my NFC based application in Automated test  environment. I have different Mifare family card(ultralight/classic). I want to Automate my test cases completely for different card.

Is there any test Automation (apart from Junit) s/w or some way to do it? Please ignore my mistakes.

Thanks in advance.